# Magento 2: Override radio.phtml for bundle

Tags: magento2, layout, bundle

I would like to override the output of a radio button rendering for a bundle in Magento 2.

In catalog_product_view_type_bundle.xml I found the following code:

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.options.wrapper">
    <block class="Magento\Bundle\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Type\Bundle" name="product.info.bundle.options" as="type_bundle_options" template="catalog/product/view/type/bundle/options.phtml" before="-">
        <block class="Magento\Bundle\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Type\Bundle\Option\Radio" name="product.info.bundle.options.radio" as="radio"/>
    </block>
</referenceBlock>
```

I tried to override the template with

```
<block class="Magento\Bundle\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Type\Bundle\Option\Radio" name="product.info.bundle.options.radio" as="radio" template="Magento_Bundle::templates/catalog/product/view/type/bundle/option/radio-alternative.phtml"/>
```

But the new template is not used for rendering. Is there any idea around what could be wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `templates` from template path from xml

```
<block class="Magento\Bundle\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Type\Bundle\Option\Radio" name="product.info.bundle.options.radio" as="radio" template="Magento_Bundle::catalog/product/view/type/bundle/option/radio-alternative.phtml"/>
```

The location of file `radio-alternative.phtml` must be at

> app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Bundle/templates/catalog/product/view/type/bundle/option/radio-alternative.phtml

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is there a way to input this into Layout XML of the bundle product? <referenceBlock> is not allowed there. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
<block class="Magento\Bundle\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Type\Bundle\Option\Radio" name="product.info.bundle.options.radio" as="radio" template="Magento_Bundle::templates/catalog/product/view/type/bundle/option/radio-alternative.phtml"/>
```

To

```
<block class="Magento\Bundle\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Type\Bundle\Option\Radio" name="product.info.bundle.options.radio" as="radio" template="yourModuleNamespace_ModuleName::catalog/product/view/type/bundle/option/radio-alternative.phtml"/>
```

and make sure your file `radio-alternative.phtml` should exist here : `yourmodule/view/templates/frontend/catalog/product/view/type/bundle/option/`

Answer (score 1):

```
Override radio.phtml for bundle product

1. Create Layout catalog_product_view_type_bundle.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.bundle.options.radio">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendorname_Modulename::catalog/product/view/type/bundle/option/radio.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
  </body>
</page>  

Template Define

Vendorname/Modulename/view/frontend/templates/catalog/product/view/type/bundle/option/radio.phtml
```

[image]